# Spatial Duplicates & Address Duplicates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, address

I am working on ArcGIS 10.0 and I want to SELECT (and not remove) all the spatial and address duplicates from the attribute table in a layer, either by code or in a table window or else with spatial operations.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to revise it with more details of your precise requirement, please?  For example, are you looking to do this with code, with the attribute table window open, etc.  Also, what version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the find [identical tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000054000000) that will create a new table with the spatial duplicate. It can also use some fields so that you have both spatial and Address duplicates. It will yield a new table with a feat_seq column that groups the identical features. If you use "summarize table", you derive the count of duplicates for each "feat_seq" value. Then you can join the resulting table with your feature class in order to select your duplicates (count > 1).